# Codeigniter Pagination view

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, pagination

I am new on Codeigniter and I need to find out the way.

Controller, here I fetch my data :

```
<?php
class PropertyModel extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

 public function pagination()

{
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->library('pagination');
$this->load->library('table');
$config['base_url']='http://localhost/Goldenacre/property/pagination';
$config['total_rows']= $this->db->get('property')->num_rows();
$config['per_page']= 10;
$config['num_links']=5;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);



$config['total_rows']=$this->db->get('property')->num_rows();


$data['records']=$this->db->get('property',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

$this->load->view('listvieww',$data);

$this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

**View page**

```
<html>
<h1>My Pagination</h1>`

<?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>

<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

My whole code is work but its not working as per my requirements. I need to show it like this.

Its all shown in a table, I need to show its on my way like in div or `<article> </article>` tag or in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the config array you send to the Paging library, you can add

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<article>';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</article>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

You can also Customize the first, last, next, previous and current  links: have a look on the documentation here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html